# Fatal error: Allowed memory size, when using ip2long function

Tags: php, ip

I am using the ip2Long function below,

```
function ip_range($start, $end) {
    $start = ip2long($start);
    $end = ip2long($end);
    return array_map('long2ip', range($start, $end) );
}

$range_one = "86.188.249.48 ";
$range_two = "86.188.249.55";
print_r( ip_range($range_one, $range_two) );
```

But I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 32 bytes) in /home/site/public_html/path/checkrange.php on
>   line 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$range_one` is not considered a valid IP. If you remove the space off the end then this works for me:

`$range_one = "86.188.249.48";`

To avoid this in the future, you should `trim` your values:

```
$start = ip2long(trim($start));
$end = ip2long(trim($end));
```

Answer (score 0):

The is a **space** at the end of the variable.

```
$range_one = "86.188.249.48 ";
                        // ^ Remove this
```